# Obtaining Measurements from DICOM Images

Tags: image, dicom, measure

I have a single DICOM image and I want to obtain real measurements from it in mm.

I have the "PixelSpacing" information: [1.4063 1.4063]. Does that mean that 1 pixel corresponds to 1.4063 mm in both the x and y planes?

I also have SliceThickness: 8. Does that mean that the distance between slices in the z direction is 8 mm? Thanks!

---

Thanks everyone, that's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**about PixelSpacing:** Yes, your assumption is correct. Be careful: Unlike you would intuitively think, the first value is the y-dimension and the second the x-dimension (see PS3.3 10.7.1.3)

**about SliceThickness:** No, the slice thickness is the width of the area which was reconstructed from the raw signal to calculate the pixel values. Neighboring slices may overlap. The distance between slices is not explicitly encoded in DICOM, but it can be calculated from the difference between the Image Position Patient attributes (0020,0032) of 2 neighboring slices.

Comment: As a complement to this answer, check out the following page: http://nipy.org/nibabel/dicom/dicom_orientation.html